# Jhipster ERROR! Error looking for otherEntity Authority at ~(Table Names)

Tags: jhipster

I am new to jhipster and trying to import an existing project. When I am creating an entity with just 2 fields and no foreign key mapping at all, I get this exception :

ERROR! Error looking for otherEntity Authority at ~(Table Names)

The authority is missing in .jhipster folder and I cannot create an Authority entity because I get this : ERROR! Is not possible to override built in Authority

Application is build on springboot.

"jhipsterVersion": "7.1.0",
"applicationType": "monolith",

Will appreciate any help on this one. Thanks

Comment: Please show your JDL. Of course you cannot name an entity Authority this is reserved by Jhipster, same for User

Comment: Also, check the files inside the `.jhipster` directory, you probably have an entity referencing `Authority`.